# Select param when not null or another param

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.task_id,b.task_id) as 
task_id,b.task_name as name
FROM table_a as a FULL OUTER JOIN table_b as b ON 
a.task_id = b.task_id
```

**If b.task_name is null It will be**

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.task_id,b.task_id) as 
task_id,a.task_name as name
FROM table_a as a FULL OUTER JOIN table_b as b ON 
a.task_id = b.task_id
```

How to add where to select param from table a if not null or from another table if its be null when using fullouter join

- Table_a:  primary_id,task_id, task_name = [{1,1,"name1ofa"}, {2,2,"name2ofa"}]
- Talbe_b: primary_id,task_id, task_name = [{1,1,"name1ofb"}, {2,2,null}]
- Expect selected query: [{1,"name1ofb"}, {2,"name2ofa"}]
  I want is the priority of b.task_name to be higher than a.taske_name

Comment: Unclear question. Look at `coalesce`, `union`, `full outer join` for ideas.

Comment: @buscu, post some sample data and expected result.

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: dnms is postgresql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `INNER JOIN` instead of `FULL OUTER JOIN` because you want to get a result that matches `task_id` from those tables.

Then `COALESCE` function will return the first non-null value in parameters, so you might use `b.task_name` be the first parameter

```
SELECT a.task_id , 
       COALESCE(b.task_name,a.task_name) as name
FROM table_a as a 
INNER JOIN table_b as b 
ON a.task_id = b.task_id
```

Comment: sorry, Its just example, but it's actually a full outer join. I want is the priority of b.task_name to be higher than a.taske_name

Comment: how when b.task_name and a.task_name has different string

Comment: still Full outer join but with COALESCE I resovled